# How to get the content in a div using php

Tags: php

In my application i am trying to get the google indexed pages and i came to know that the number is available in following div

```
<div id="resultStats"> About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) </div>
```

now my question is how to extract the number from above div in a web page

Comment: DOMDocument::getElementByID

Answer (score 4):

Never user regexp to parse HTML. (See: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))

Use a HTML parser, like SimpleDOM (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

You can the use CSS rules to select:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$divContent =  $html->find('div#resultStats', 0)->plaintext;

$matches = array();
preg_match('/([0-9,]+)/', $divContent, $matches);
echo $matches[1];

Outputs: "1,960,000"
```

Comment: it will print `About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) ` but he wanted number so regex is neccesary.

Comment: Once you've got the string out of the div, extracting the number from the string should be trivial.

Comment: Quoting OP *now my question is how to extract the number from above div in a web page* I don't write that it's bad solution to use file_get_html() it's good but that's not what he wants. At least I understand it in that way. He wanted to know how to extract particular number.

Comment: Yeah, missed that. Added a regexp.

Comment: This regexp prints `0.38 seconds` ehhh ;) Moreover you overwrite the result of function find() which is senseless too.

Comment: Now stealing regex from my answer which was **bad** haha :) My answer can be modifed not to use `<div>` and it will work to :> So in the end you use external library + regex(which is bad) - brilliant.

Comment: I'd say our regexps is pretty different i'd say, yeah, I didnt read the full question at first, but [0-9,]+ I came up with myself, but it's kind the goto answer for anyone id say if trying to match 1,323,232,232.. etc.

Comment: It helps me to move further.Thankz a ton

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '<div id="resultStats"> About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) </div> ';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/<div id="resultStats"> About ([0-9,]+?) results[^<]+<\/div>/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds)
        [1] => 1,960,000 
      )
```

This is simple regex with subpatterns

- `([0-9,]+?)` - means 0-9 numbers and , character at least 1 time and not greedy.
- `[^<]+` - means every character but < more than 1 time

`echo $matches[1];` - will print the number you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex ( preg_match ) for that

```
$your div_string = '<div id="resultStats"> About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) </div>';

preg_match('/<div.*>(.*)<\/div>/i', $your div_string , $result);

print_r( $result );
```

output will be

```
Array  (
   [0] => <div id="resultStats"> About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) </div>
   [1] =>  About 1,960,000 results (0.38 seconds) 
)
```

in this way you can get content inside div

Comment: It'll match everything between the first opening <div> and the last closing </div> in the document.

Comment: @GordonM but he want from specific div.

Comment: i want the number from that div.but it gives something more that i dont want